# How to preserve line correct line numbers with karma-babel-preprocessor and PhantomJs?

Tags: karma-runner

When I use the [documented configuration](https://github.com/babel/karma-babel-preprocessor) of karma-babel-preprocessor like this

```
module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    preprocessors: {
      'src/**/*.js': ['babel'],
      'test/**/*.js': ['babel']
    },
    babelPreprocessor: {
      options: {
        sourceMap: 'inline'
      },
      filename: function (file) {
        return file.originalPath.replace(/\.js$/, '.es5.js');
      },
      sourceFileName: function (file) {
        return file.originalPath;
      }
    }
  });
};
```

I get wrong source line numbers, e.g.

```
 at /var/www/edu-web/tests/jasmine/services/image/imageServiceTest.es5.js:77
```

There is no support for source maps by default, so it is no surprise. However, the problem here is that `imageServiceTest.es5.js` file is deleted after karma finishes so I have no choice but to guess where the unit test fail (on which line) and that's slow.

There is a solution in the [issue](https://github.com/babel/karma-babel-preprocessor/issues/4) for Chrome (not PhantomJs). Can I fix my configuration for PhantomJs as well?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a solution when looking to the Babel documentation:

> `retainLines` Retain line numbers. This will lead to wacky code
>   but is handy for scenarios where you can't use source maps.
>
> NOTE: This will obviously not retain the columns.

(http://babeljs.io/docs/usage/options/)

My final configuration:

```
module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    preprocessors: {
      'src/**/*.js': ['babel'],
      'test/**/*.js': ['babel']
    },
    babelPreprocessor: {
      options: {
        sourceMap: 'inline',
        retainLines: true // NEW LINE
      },
      filename: function (file) {
        return file.originalPath.replace(/\.js$/, '.es5.js');
      },
      sourceFileName: function (file) {
        return file.originalPath;
      }
    }
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone ever looks for a way to do it while using the @babel/standalone code
You can add:

```
<script>
        Babel.registerPlugin('set-retain-lines', {
          manipulateOptions: (opts) => {
              opts.generatorOpts = {
                  ...opts.generatorOpts,
                  retainLines: true
              };
              return opts;
          }
        });
    </script>
```

And then add `data-plugins="set-retain-lines"` to the relevant script tag